# How do you move an SVG to the right?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

Sorry if this is a very nube question but I want to shift my SVG over to the right. How would I do that? I'm using typescript and react. Here is my code.

```
<div className="img">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3k3pNcp/Untitleyd-1.png" alt="" width={1850} height={2000}/>
                {/* <embed src="https://i.ibb.co/ww53Yhy/image2535.png" type="" /> */}
            </div>
            <svg className="pfd-svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        
                <Horizon />
                
                {/* <VSI /> */}
{/* 
                <path className="gray-bg" d="M13 100, h100 v560 h -100 Z" /> */}
                {/* <path className="gray-bg" d="M600 100, h100 v560 h-100 Z" />
                <path className="gray-bg" d="M130 10, h450, v50, h-450 Z" />
                <path className="gray-bg" d="M142 785, h412, c -103 -140, -306 -140, -412 0 Z" /> */}
                

                {/* FMA lines */}
                <BlackOutlineWhiteLine d="M286 10, v50" />
                <BlackOutlineWhiteLine d="M428 10, v50" />
                <FMA />

                <SpeedTape />
                <CommandSpeed />
                <SpeedScroller />
                <MachGS />

                
                {/* <CommandAlt />
                
                
                <Minimums />
                <RadioAltimeter /> */}
                <LateralDeviationScale />
                <VerticalDeviationScale />
            </svg>
```

Comment: Add a translate transform to anything you want to shift. You can use a CSS style transform or an SVG attribute transform.

Comment: @RobertLongson can I put a translate transform on the entire SVG and/or can I just do it on each item in the SVG?

Comment: whichever you need.

Comment: What do you mean by "shift my SVG over to the right"? Is it the content of the SVG that needs to move or is it the SVG image that needs to move. This could just be a styling issue, and if so, what is the context: Would it be fine to float it to the right, using grid, flex or positioning absolute or fixed.